# android: Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(), rate is not fixed?

Tags: android, android-emulator, timer, timertask

I want to make my `View` class to draw something every 1 second, thus I used `Timertask` and `Timer`, and here is my code:

```
private TimerTask timerTask;
private Timer t = new Timer();
public void dataEmitter(){
    timerTask = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            postInvalidate();
        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 2000, 1000);
}
```

But then I found that even though this method is called repeatedly, but it is not at fixed rate. Sometimes it is very fast, but sometimes it is very slow. So I am wondering if this only happens to the simulator? If not, how can I call a method at exactly fixed rate in Android?

Answer (score 0):

try to call it this way:

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

also you have to make sure that  postInvalidate(); method will not take more than 1 second to be executed.